# AWS: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, connection

I am facing "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" error.
I am not able to ssh my instance.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.
Below is the debug information

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/aaa.pem ubuntu@52.xxx.xx.xx -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.xxx.xx.xx [52.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/aaa.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/aaa.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

This actually happened quite a few times already.  sometimes it happened once a day, sometimes weeks.  I wasn't able to see any error logs.

What I had to do in order to fix is (rebooting never worked) to stop then start the instance.

I even tried launching another instance from a backup image I made awhile back then re-deployed my codes since all settings are the same, just need the new code then dns into this new ip instance.  I tried using launching because there were at least two times the stopping took like 20 minutes and still saying stopping....so I launched a new instance.  THEN this new instance have the same thing happen just out of no where that I can't ssh into my instance, site isn't running.  So I had to do the previous steps again.

Any suggestion on what might be going on and how I can do checks?